# Vimeo advanced api, delete apps

Tags: php, vimeo

I'm using Vimeo's advanced api and in the process I've created a number of apps in the My API Apps page.

It's not causing a problem but is it possible to delete the apps I'm not using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment they can not be removed from the app page. Contact vimeo at https://vimeo.com/help/contact